# ¿Cómo adquirió "sursuncorda" un significado tan diferente a su etimología?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, significado, historia, latín

En el [Diccionario de la lengua española](https://dle.rae.es/) de la Real Acaemia Española se recoge [**sursuncorda**](https://dle.rae.es/sursuncorda?) como

> Del lat. *sursum corda* 'arriba los corazones'.
>
> 1. m. coloq. Supuesto personaje anónimo de mucha importancia. *No lo haré aunque lo mande el sursuncorda*.

Y parece que esa entrada, con exactamente la misma definición y el mismo ejemplo de uso, está presente en el diccionario de la Real Academia Española desde la edición de 1925.

Curiosamente en el [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) no hay recogido mas que un único caso, mientras que en el [CREA](http://corpus.rae.es/creanet.html) no hay ninguno y en el [CORPES XXI](http://web.frl.es/CORPES/view/inicioExterno.view) solamente dos casos.

Llama la atención la manifiesta discrepancia entre la etimología (del lat. "arriba los corazones") y el significado ("Supuesto personaje anónimo de mucha importancia"). ¿Hay alguna explicación conocida de ese cambio tan marcado?

Comment: Realmente curioso. Es una locución que viene de la misa en latín. En italiano se usa a veces como expresión para dar ánimos (pero no es muy común). No tenía ni idea de este significado en español.

Comment: En este sitio web se explica algo, pero no sé qué credibilidad puede tener: https://www.cinconoticias.com/sursum-corda-significado-e-historia-expresion/.

Comment: @Charo: En español yo solo la he usado/escuchado como la locución latina (sursum corda, con *m*, dos palabras) y con el sentido original.

Comment: @Charo: En el Fichero General de la Real Academia solo aparecen 9 fichas al buscar "sursuncorda". La única interesante es http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_S/LETRA_S_PDF/SURSUNCORDA/00001293.pdf en que se recoge "Sursún corda (El). Dios" -  en 2 palabras, y sin más explicaciones o comentarios ¿?

Answer (score 1):

**Cuestión:**  **Sursum Corda!**

¿Cómo adquirió "sursuncorda" un significado tan diferente a su etimología?

¿Hay alguna explicación conocida de ese cambio tan marcado?

---

Al principio solo creía que era una locución en Latín  "Sursum Corda", "¡Arriba el Corazón!", que se expresaba en la Liturgia de la Misa y que a base de utilizarlo lo había convertido en un sustantivo, "Sursumcorda", utilizado popularmente como un nombre de alguien importantísimo, pero como suele ocurrir, nada es lo que parece. Fue interesante analizar el tema.

- **Sursum Corda Liturgico**

*El texto original estaba escrito en Griego, pero sólo nos queda en Latín.*

*Versión antigua*

---

Sacerdote: Dominus vobiscum. - El Señor este con Vosotros.

Feligreses: Et omnes dicant. - Y todos dicen

Sacerdote: Et cum spiritu tuo. **Sursum Corda**. - Y con tu Espíritu. Arriba el Corazón. (Levantemos el Corazón) (La tradición dice que la gente al oír aquí "**Sursum Corda**" se ponía en pie (levantaba) para responder con el siguiente párrafo)

Feligreses: Habemus ad Dominum. Lo tenemos (levantado) hacia el Señor

Sacerdote: Gratias agamus Domino, (Deo Nostro). - Gracias hacia el Señor. (Demos gracias al Señor, nuestro Dios)

Feligreses: Dignum et iustum est - Digno y Justo es (Es Justo y Necesario)

---

Algunos autores piensan que al principio era el texto utilizado para la ordenación de un nuevo obispo y luego la expresión ha sido utilizada en el Rito Romano, el Mozárabe y en general por la traditio Apostolica... Nunca se sabrá realmente como fue ó de donde provino el original.

---

Sin embargo entre el Sursum Corda de la Liturgia y la expresión popular pronunciada como Sursumcorda, el hilo conductor se encontraba en lo que significó en cada etapa ó momento histórico para gran parte de la sociedad y su posterior expansión ó utilización de la locución para no incurrir en maldiciones contra la Iglesia o figuras afines de proximidad, entremedias había un canto de lucha antiliberal.

- **Sursum Corda como Canto ó Consigna Tradicionalista**

Para entender ese cambio en su interpretación  y lo que el "Sursum Corda" significaba lejos de la Liturgia, hay que remontarse a la Revolución Española de 1868 y al contexto histórico que España vivió a partir de entonces.

La Revolución de Septiembre del 68, supuso el destronamiento y exilio de la Reina Isabel II a Francia, una nueva Constitución, la de 1869, la búsqueda de una nueva dinastía, la Primera República y como consecuencia de todo ello una respuesta convulsa y sucesiva en el país a partir de entonces. Respuesta social tradicionalista, que se irá trasmitiendo en el tiempo cada vez, con una mayor intensidad hasta desembocar en la Guerra Civil de 1936-1939.

No hay más que leer a Gaspar Núñez de Arce en su poema (Sursum Corda), Antonio de Valbuena en su obra (Sursum Corda), Francisco García Rodrigo (Los principios católicos ante la razón) y otros autores contra-reformistas y contra-revolucionarios, la mayoría de corte tradicional y algún otro liberal que no estaba de acuerdo con las políticas de los sucesivos gobiernos, para comprender que el **Sursum Corda!**, se convirtió desde entonces en el gritó de protesta, de animo, disposición y de batalla para una parte importante de la sociedad Española de la época, reacia al observar como tales cambios se estaban desarrollando y afectando a esa parte social.

- **Sursuncorda Popular**

El "Sursuncorda" luego, como expresión popular, sirvió a está para encubrir cualquier tipo de supuesta blasfemia, en el sentido de palabra malsonante u ofensiva y en lugar de decir, "Me cago en Dios", se intercambiaba por "Me cago en el Sursuncorda", "Por mi, como si viene el Papa", por, "Por mi, como si viene el Sursuncorda", Díselo al Obispo, por, "Díselo al Sursuncorda", "De aquí no me levanta ni Dios", por "De aquí no me levanta ni (aunque venga) el Sursuncorda"...., e  igualmente una fórmula, utilizada para disfrazar un ataque, el meterse o molestar de manera despectiva a la parte de la sociedad más tradicionalista, nombrando la expresión que servía de emblema, en oraciones groseras y en ciertos contextos que trataban de enojar.

---

- **Sursum Corda Efectos Históricos**

Por último, entre otras muchas cosas, el "Sursum Corda", como "Arriba los Corazones" es la leyenda que está detrás, y que daría origen, al lema "Arriba España" (atribuido a los regeneracionistas) y no seria una simple imitación al modelo Italiano ó Alemán como algunos han indicado, posteriormente aparecerá el periódico del mismo nombre.

Expresión "Arriba España" que resume en palabras de *Jose María Peman en 1939*, el sentido mismo  que el tradicionalismo Español histórico tenía del "Sursum Corda" como emblema de lucha, aliento, energía ó que infundía animo a las almas afligidas por los desmanes y desordenes, en la esperanza de que manteniendo esa actitud que expresaba "Sursum Corde" la situación cambiaria.

"*La victoria definitiva de España es en estas páginas seguridad y fe. Como también es fe y seguridad la España una, grande y libre, que tras la victoria esperamos para siempre*.
*Ella será la vuelta de España a sí misma: a su camino y a su Historia. Porque la Historia que acabamos de contar no ha sido más que eso: una lucha constante por los más altos ideales del Espíritu. No servimos para cosas bajas, pequeñas o menudas. No servimos más que para las cosas altas y grandes. Por eso cuando decimos «Arriba España», en esas dos palabras, a un tiempo, resumimos nuestra Historia y ciframos nuestra esperanza. Porque lo que queremos es que España vuelva a "su sitio": al sitio que la Historia le señala. Y el sitio es ese: «Arriba». Es decir, cerca del espíritu, del ideal, de la fe... Cerca, sobre todo, de Dios.*"

---

A esto añadir que el concepto de "Verticalidad" (Sindicato Vertical, Fuerzas Armadas...), del régimen Franquista, tampoco es novedoso, ni se origina en las bases del propio sindicato ó de un concepto armonicista de la unidad de clases, sino que procede del mismo significado como adverbio que tiene la voz **Sursum o us**, en Latín "*de abajo hacia arriba, hacia lo alto, ascendiendo*" concebido durante muchos años atrás y ahora intentando darle forma. Espero que haya contribuido a esclarecer los cambios en la locución.